# iOS: Html parsing - how to ignore tags like a, li, etc.. within <p>

Tags: objective-c, ios, xpath, html-parsing, hpple

I am currently using Hpple to parse HTML, like so:

```
TFHpple *htmlParser = [TFHpple hppleWithHTMLData:[currentString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
NSString *paragraphsXpathQuery = @"//p//text()";
        NSArray *paragraphNodes = [htmlParser searchWithXPathQuery:paragraphsXpathQuery];
        if ([paragraphNodes count] > 0) {
            NSMutableArray *tempArray = [NSMutableArray array];
            for (TFHppleElement *element in paragraphNodes) {
                [tempArray addObject:[element content]];
            }
            article.paragraphs = tempArray;
        }
```

This way I get an array of paragraphs and I can use `NSString *result = [myArray componentsJoinedByString:@"\n\n"];` to compile it into a single body of text with line breakes.

However, if the html contains  tags, they are interpreted as individual entities and will get line breaked on their own right, so **at the end of the day from a line like this:**

```
<p>I went to the <a href="blablabla.html">shop</a> to get some milk!</a></p>
<p>It was awesome.</p>
```

**I get this:**

```
I went to the

shop

to get some milk!

It was awesome!
```

**And of course I would like to get this (ignore other tags inside the `p` tag):**

```
I went to the shop to get some milk!

It was awesome!
```

**Can you help me out?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSString *HTMLTags = @"<[^>]*>"; //regex to remove any html tag

NSString *htmlString = @"<html>bla bla</html>";
NSString *stringWithoutHTML = [hstmString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfRegex:myregex withString:@""];
```

don't forget to include this in your code : #import "RegexKitLite.h" here is the link to download this API : http://regexkit.sourceforge.net/#Downloads

Comment: Thank you very much! This worked for me!
You might want to correct "myRegex" to HTMLTags in your last line though. :)

NOTE to others: After importing RegexKitLite, you have to link against "-licucore" which can be done by typing -licucore in the Other linker flags line in the Build Settings!

Comment: If your projects is built for iOS 4.0 or a newer version (which is very likely) then you do not need an external library for regular expressions and should use NSRegularExpression: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class.

Answer (score 2):

**In XPath 1.0 you can do this in two steps**:

1. Select all `p` elements: `//p`
2. On each selected `p` element (used as the initial context node) evaluate this: `string()`

**Explanation**:

By definition, the result of applying the standard XPath function **[`string()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-string)** to an element is the concatenation (in document order) of all of its text-node descendants.

Comment: Hi, I'm also interested in doing this, but I don't get what you mean by *evaluate this: string()* ? Can you give some very basic example code on how to do that ?

Comment: @rdurand, How to evaluate an XPath expression is implementation dependent -- read your documentation. I can tell you how to do this in .NET with C#: use the XPathNavigator.Evaluate() method: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2c16b7x8.aspx

Comment: That's what I realized after posting the comment. As the question seemed iOS specific, I was thinking about an iOS example. I'll look into this, and it seems like @AppleDelegate gave another iOS specific solution. Thanks !

Comment: @rdurand, Whenever you have an XPath 2.0 implementation available, you'd be able to get the wanted string by evaluating a single XPath (2.0) expression.